# bash & using a variable to decide when to use 'set'?

Tags: bash, debugging, set

Looking to ascertain why when I do something like;

```
[ ${debug:=0} -gt 0 ] && set -x || set +x
```

regardless of the conditional `set -x` is enabled. The issue is that I am unable to use `${debug}` to `set +x` IF `debug=1` first.

Test case:

```
dtest(){ [ "${d:=0}" -gt 0 ] && set -x || set +x; var="abc"; echo "${var}"; }
d=0;dtest
d=1;dtest
d=0;dtest
```

Not certain if this has been asked, perhaps I am unsure of the verbiage to use.

Comment: cannot reproduce -- `dtest(){ sh -c '[ "${d:=0}" -gt 0 ] && set -x || set +x; true'; };   unset d; dtest;   d= dtest;   d=0 dtest;    d=1 dtest` prints `+ true` just once no matter what shell I've replaced `sh` with.

Comment: Why are you passing through `sh`? Using bash; `dtest(){ [ "${d:=0}" -gt 0 ] && set -x || set +x; var="abc"; echo "${abc}"; }`. I have updated the question to be more specific

Comment: still the same thing -- the first `dtest` isn't turning `-x` on, and the last is turning it off. Please change the  `echo "${abc}"` to `echo "${var}"` to make more clear ;-)

Comment: it helps to know what to search for on the web .... look for `bash short circuit logic` ..... one of the hits is here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766270/why-use-short-circuiting-boolean-logic-rather-than-if-then-else-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must reset the xtrace in the function.

```
dtest(){
  [ "${d:=0}" -gt 0 ] && set -x
  var="abc"
  echo "${var}"
  set +x
}
d=0;dtest
d=1;dtest
d=0;dtest
```

Or use a subshell :

```
dtest(){
  [ "${d:=0}" -gt 0 ] && set -x || set +x
  var="abc"
  echo "${var}"
}
d=0;(dtest)
d=1;(dtest)
d=0;(dtest)
```

Answer (score 0):

That works fine for me.

`set -x` is disabled to begin with, and with `d=0` it doesn't get set:

```
$ dtest(){ [ "${d:=0}" -gt 0 ] && set -x || set +x; var="abc"; echo "${var}"; }
$ d=0;dtest
abc
```

Here, it's set in the middle of the function, the last two commands a printed in the trace:

```
$ d=1;dtest
+ var=abc
+ echo abc
abc
```

Here, `set -x` is in effect from the last run of the function, and gets disabled in the middle of the function. The trace is not printed for the last two commands, after `set +x` runs.

```
$ d=0;dtest
+ d=0
+ dtest
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ set +x
abc
```

If you want to disable tracing unconditionally at the end of the function, you'll 
have to add a call to `set +x`.

Alternatively, to have the change take effect only inside the function, you can use `local -` (in current versions of Bash) in the beginning of the function or save the value of `$-` manually before making changes and set/reset tracing based on the saved value at the end. Running the function in a subshell would have a similar effect, but in that case, any changes to variables in the function would also not be visible outside it.